# OOP - instance of a class is created, a different class should be created , an array stores every new instance created

Tags: python, arrays, class, oop, instance

I am having trouble understanding the following instructions in an exercise:

1. Create another class Location which has two properties called coordinate and name.
2. **Each time an instance of Location is created,
   a class Coordinate should be created that gets passed in the coordinates that should be given as arguments when creating Location**.
3. Further, you should create a return_location method that returns the name of the location.
4. **An array locations which is a class variable of Location stores every Location that is created.**

So far I have this:

```
class Coordinate:
    def __init__(self,latitude,longitude):
        self.latitude = latitude
        self.longitude = longitude
    def return_coord(self):
        return self.latitude, self.longitude

class Location:
  locations = [0]

  def __init__(self,coordinate,name):
    self.coordinate = coordinate 
    self.name = name 
    locations.append(self) #store every location created on the array locations  

  def return_location():
    return self.name
```

But I am not sure if I am indeed doing the second step correctly
and when trying to do the 4th step it shows me the error: `NameError: Name ´locations´ is not defined, did you mean Location?`

Comment: "... A class Coordinate should be created..." If doing this exercise/course is not obligatory for you, skip it and look for something more adequate. Dynamic class creation is OK, but definitely not in this case - and class vs instance should never be confused. Learning material cannot use this terms interchangeably.

Answer (score 0):

For the error you're receiving, you should be using `Location.locations.append(self)` rather than `locations.append(self)`

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of step 2 is that `Location.__init__()` should receive `latitude` and `longitude` as separate arguments, and you need to create a `Location` instance from them.

There's no need to put `0` in the initial `locations` list. It should start out empty, and you append to it when you create new `Location` instances.

```
class Location:

  locations = [] 

  def __init__(self,lat, long,name):
    self.coordinate = Coordinate(lat, long)
    self.name = name 
    locations.append(self) #store every location created on the array locations  

  def return_location():
    return self.name
```

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is this. Corrections include: `locations = [0]` replaced with `locations = []`, `locations.append(self)` replaced with `Location.locations.append(self)`

```
class Coordinate:
    def __init__(self,latitude,longitude):
        self.latitude = latitude
        self.longitude = longitude
    def return_coord(self):
        return self.latitude, self.longitude

class Location:
  locations = []

  def __init__(self,coordinate,name):
    self.coordinate = coordinate 
    self.name = name 
    Location.locations.append(self) #store every location created on the array locations  

  def return_location(self):
    return self.name

l1 = Location(Coordinate(40.70, -74.04), 'NY')
l2 = Location(Coordinate(-22.90, -43.19), 'Rio')

for location in Location.locations:
  print(location.coordinate.return_coord(), location.return_location())
```

Hope this helps.